# Use JavaScript to show warning message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to show a warning message if the users select Yes from the radio button.  My issue is that the warning message is only showing Yes but i would like to show Yes and No so the user can select either of them. When they select Yes then i am deleting some records but all that is being done in the code behind.  What am i doing wrong here?

```
<div>

    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Yes</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">No</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:RadioButtonList>

</div>
```

here is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var selectlistId =   document.getElementsByName('<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>');
    selectlist = document.getElementByid(selectlistId);

    selectlist.onchange = function () {
        if (selectlist.options[selectlist.selectedIndex].value == "YES") {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
                __doPostBack(selectlistId, '');
            } else {
                // User selected NO, so change DropDownList back to 0.
                selectlist.selectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be => `var selectlistId =   document.getElementById('<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>');`

Comment: postbacks work with .name, not id, change to __doPostBack(selectlist.name, '');

Comment: i have tried that but still i am not getting any warning message that shows yes or no option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

postbacks work with .name, not id, try changing to

```
__doPostBack(selectlist.name, '');
```

and see if that helps

As for the warning message, you have to attach the event handler to the input elements inside the radio button list. The radio button list itself is a table of options. So off the top of my head, something like this should work

```
$('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%> input').click(function(){
    var $rb = $(this);
    if ($rb.val() == "YES"){
        ...
    }
});
```

EDIT:
I added a code sample demonstrating a working confirm box NOT using jquery:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                     OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:listitem value="0">Yes</asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem value="1" selected="True">No</asp:listitem>

</asp:RadioButtonList>


<script>

    (function () {

        //without jquery
        var rbl = document.getElementById('<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%>');

        var chks = rbl.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var x = 0; x < chks.length; x++) {
            var chk = chks[x];

            chk.onclick = function () {
                var that = this;
                if (that.value == "0") {

                    //selected yes
                    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {

                        //confirmed yes
                        __doPostBack(rbl.name, '');
                    }
                    else {
                        //confirmed no
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //selected no
                }
            }
        }



    })();

</script>
```

Comment: still i am not getting any warning message.

Comment: Aye, but without __doPostBack(selectlist.name, ''); you would get no postback. See my edit to the answer.

Comment: Eric, i have been trying all day yesterday but still could not get it to work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ClientID="static"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
       <asp:ListItem Value="0">Yes</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">No</asp:ListItem>

  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**JS**

```
$("#RadioButtonList1").change(function(){

   /// Do what you want

 });
```

**Explanation**: You might want to add static ID(ClientID="static") to the asp.net control and then attach an event to that ID.

Answer (score 0):

The confirm dialog only shows yes or cancel. How about using a jquery dialog? This will allow you to change the text in the dialog box for your different options. API documentation is [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).